# Is a complete intersection satisfying Jacobian matrix smooth criterion a smooth variety?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra

Every scheme here is over complex number.

Let $X \subset  (\mathbb{C}^*)^n$ be a complete intersection with $X$ defined by the ideal $I \subset \mathbb{C}[x_{1}^{\pm},\dots,x_{n}^{\pm}]$ generated by $r$ equations $f_1,\dots,f_r$. Moreover, if the rank of the matrix $(\partial f_i /\partial x_j)_{ij}$ is $r$, then is $X$  a smooth variety?

This is of course true if $I$ is radical, that is, $X$ is a variety. But I don't know any information about $I$.  Actually, in my problem, I just want to know whether $I$ is reduced under the condition that the generators satisfying the Jacobian matrix smooth criterion(i.e. rank$(\partial f_i /\partial x_j)_{ij}=r$).

Comment: You say "of course" it is true when $I$ is radical, but how is the radical condition relevant in any justification?  It is true without the radical property, due to the functorial criterion for smoothness -- e.g., see Proposition 7(c) in 2.2 of "Neron Models" -- and the fact that the functorial criterion implies the power series property for completed local rings at closed points when working with finite type schemes over an algebraically closed field. 

Comment: This is really differential geometry, not algebraic geometry (although it is true in the algebraic setting as well, when the proof is written appropriately).  Your $r$ functions give a map $f:(\mathbb{C}^*)^n \to \mathbb{C}^r$.  The variety $X$ is $f^{-1}(0)$, and the condition on the matrix says that $0$ is a regular value of $f$.  So $X$ is a smooth manifold.  Near any point $p\in X$, $X$ is the transverse intersection of the $r$ hypersurfaces $f_1=f_2=\cdots f_r = 0$, and these hypersurfaces are smooth at $p$.